# How does Paypal structure button data before encryption?

Tags: php, encryption, paypal, ssl-certificate, pkcs#7

Currently I've done alot searching on how data should be structured before PKCS7 encryption for proper use within the Paypal buy-now button. So far, the best data I've found so far pertaining to data structure is an Paypal example code which demonstrates how a encrypted button appears on your website (this can be found here:https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/xcl/rec/ewp-techview-outside)

At first glance, my results seem to be exactly as demonstrated within the Paypal eaxmple link, except that when i proceed to click the button i get a Paypal error saying "We were unable to decrypt the certificate id". Therefore I think that the problem is either how the data is structured or the actual encryption itself (I've also done alot of debugging and have made sure that all certificates and keys are being successfully registered ). The code below demonstrates the button that my php code creates.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but23.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it\'s fast, free and secure!">
  <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----MIIH6QYJKM585oH7A[to much data to show]9QRQIpFZzRK6cJu6QQO+q/xfiw==-----END PKCS7-----">
</form>
```

This is my data before encryption:

```
cert_id=9CE6NSORUBVMC cmd=_xclick business=sales@mycompany.com item_name=Cat Litter #40 amount=12.95 no_shipping=1 return=http://test183653.comli.com/MainPage.php cancel_return=http://test183653.comli.com/MainPage.php no_note=1 currency_code=USD bn=PP-BuyNowBF
```

I'm currently using the format above as a result of piecing bits and pieces of info on the internet but it doesn't seem to work (also doesn't work when i remove all the spaces in the string). Thus,

**MAIN QUESTION:** Can anyone tell me or point me in the right direction to learn the proper format of the data before encryption?

For Anyone interested to check if it is the code that creates the errors through improper encryption, the function which encrypts data can be found below:

```
function encryptButton($parameters) {

    if (($this->certificateID == '') ||
    !IsSet($this->certificate) ||
    !IsSet($this->paypalCertificate)) {
      return FALSE;
    }

    $clearText = '';
    $encryptedText = '';

    $clearText = 'cert_id='.$this->certificateID;

    foreach (array_keys($parameters) as $key) {

      $clearText .= "\n{$key}={$parameters[$key]}";
    }

    $clearFile = tempnam($this->tempFileDirectory, 'cle');
    $signedFile = preg_replace('/cle/', 'signed', $clearFile);
    $encryptedFile = preg_replace('/cle/', 'encrypted', $clearFile);

    $out = fopen($clearFile, 'wb');
    fwrite($out, $clearText); 
    fclose($out);

    //openssl_pkcs7_sign occurs here
    if (!openssl_pkcs7_sign($clearFile, $signedFile, $this->certificate, $this->privateKey, array(), PKCS7_BINARY)) {
      return FALSE;
    }

    $signedData = explode("\n\n", file_get_contents($signedFile));

    $out = fopen($signedFile, 'wb');
    fwrite($out, base64_decode($signedData[1]));
    fclose($out);

    //openssl_pkcs7_encrypt occurs here
    if (!openssl_pkcs7_encrypt($signedFile, $encryptedFile, $this->paypalCertificate, array(), PKCS7_BINARY)) {
      return FALSE;
    }

    $encryptedData = explode("\n\n", file_get_contents($encryptedFile));

    $encryptedText = $encryptedData[1];

    @unlink($clearFile);
    @unlink($signedFile);
    @unlink($encryptedFile);

    return $encryptedText;

  }


  function getEncryptedString($params) {
  return "-----BEGIN PKCS7-----".str_replace("\n", "", $this->encryptButton($params))."-----END PKCS7-----"; }
```

}

Comment: you can just create the encrypted string properly using one of the two methods PayPal provides: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/

Comment: yes i'm currently attempting to use the EWP method and have already created and uploaded the necessary public certificates and private keys EDIT: I should also add that this button needs to have dynamic content because it will be updated from a dynamic shopping cart (thats why i dont just use the Paypal button creator tool)

Comment: why are you not using the java provided by payPal?

Comment: Well partly because i don't know how to automate the command line to automatically create these buttons. This is important to me because there has to be a new buy-now button with freshly updated shopping cart information as soon as the user navigates to the shopping cart page. Is There a language i could use that could be called from php and execute a command line for creating the encrypted buttons with information passed from PHP? mabye even php itself?

Comment: `exec('java .....');` i wouldent bother with the encryption myself.

Comment: turns out my current host does not support the exec() function :(

Comment: Easier to move hosts than this reverse engineering, but good luck with that.